# Why combining AND & OR operators at the same level of a WHERE clause cause partitions not to be pruned

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a BQ table which is partitioned by the `date_hit` field, which is a `DATE` type. Today, one of the analysts I work with sent me this query saying that partitions where not being pruned:

```
SELECT
  * -- simplified for the example
FROM mytable
WHERE
  date_hit = "2022-10-28"
  AND event_label LIKE "%entrar%"
  OR event_label LIKE "%aderir %"
```

Indeed, this query was retrieving 32TB of data, so partitions where not being pruned even if we were specifying the exact date we wanted to retrieve. After reading the query, I guessed that what she was really trying to write was:

```
SELECT
  * -- simplified for the example
FROM mytable
WHERE
  date_hit = "2022-10-28"
  AND (
    event_label LIKE "%entrar%"
    OR event_label LIKE "%aderir %"
  )
```

and by applying this change the partitions were pruned properly, and the query only retrieved 47GB.

What I'm trying to understand is, what was happening with the first query? Why was it querying so much data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL (and most progamming languages), `AND` has higher precedence than `OR`.  So the original `WHERE` clause was being evaluated as this:

```sql
WHERE (date_hit = "2022-10-28" AND event_label LIKE "%entrar%") OR
      event_label LIKE "%aderir %"
```

If you intend to use the second version, then you must use explicit parentheses:

```sql
WHERE date_hit = "2022-10-28" AND
      (event_label LIKE "%entrar%" OR event_label LIKE "%aderir %")
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I see it now on this simple scenario, but how would a more complex clause be evaluated? For example: `WHERE a AND b OR c AND d OR e AND f AND g`

Comment: What you wrote would be evaluated as: `WHERE (a AND b) OR (c AND d) OR (e AND f AND g)` ... regarding what your intention is, you would need to state that.

Comment: OK, now I fully got it! Thank you so much for your time